# What does this line of script mean?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the following line of code in a batch(.bat) file that I have to run:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\ArcGIS\bin\ESRIRegAsm.exe" /p:desktop MfeArcGis10.UI.dll
```

When I run this batch file, the ESRIRegAsm.exe is executed but I get the following error:

[image]

Can someone explain what this batch script is doing. From what I understand it is executing the executable with two arguments, however I do not know what the first argument means. Also what does the given error mean? How would I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, take a look at [Calling esriRegasm manually (outside an ArcGIS-installation)](https://web.archive.org/web/20180418054244/http://geekswithblogs.net/mapfel/archive/2011/04/26/145053.aspx).

It looks like **MfeArcGis10.UI.dll** is a plugin / dynamic linked library (DLL). It is necessary to register components/classes of this DLL in Windows registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` for usage by *ArcGIS*. This registry key requires administrator privileges for write access.

So you need to right click on this batch file and click in context menu on *Run as Administrator*, enter the password for the administrator account, and then the registration process should work.

Note: The batch file must be in same directory as file **MfeArcGis10.UI.dll** or **ESRIRegAsm.exe** will not be able to find the plugin file containing the information which must be added to Windows registry.

More useful pages [How to register COM components](https://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000002pv000000) containing also a link to [ESRIRegAsm utility](https://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000004n6000000). The last page explains option `/p:`.